# Выделить из строки полный путь к файлу

Tags: регулярные-выражения, windows, файлы, golang

К примеру, есть строка вида

```
"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\POWERPNT.EXE\" \"C:\\Users\\Test\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\INetCache\\1234\\Презентация.pptx\" /ou \"\""
```

Есть какой-то общий способ выделить из неё сущности, которые являются именами файлов?
Пробовал использовать регулярки, но пробелы в пути их смущают.
К примеру:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.])+
```

Работает для простых случаев, но не для примера, описанного выше.
Быть может, есть какая-то библиотека для Go для таких задач, или можно как-то подправить мою регулярку.

Comment: пробелы не попадают под `\w`. так что сначала аккуратно разбирать на параметры, деля их по пробелам, разумеется не рассматривая пробелы внутри кавычек. А потом уже среди параметров искать что то похожее на путь

Comment: Чем определяется «имя файла»? `POWERPNT.EXE` ведь тоже файл.

Comment: Если имена файлов могут быть только в кавычках, то регулярное  выражение должно просто брать строки между кавычек. Ну а там уже от того, что является файлом, а что нет зависит. Ну и так далее. Не хватает данных. И да, эту строку лучше представить в обратных кавычках, чтобы меньше было мусора.

Answer (score 0):

Это выражение:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w]+)\\(?:[\w\s\(\)]+\\)+([\wА-Яа-я\.\s]+)
```

выберет из строки все имена файлов. Т.е. "POWERPNT.EXE" и "Презентация.pptx". Если надо только одно из них то нужно немного поправить выражение.